# Set and get text from spinner

Tags: java, android, xml, spinner

I am trying to set text to a spinner like you would do with a `TextView` and also get text like that. I want the Spinner to behave like the one in the Contacts App where you can set a Date for Birthdays or so and `onClick` open a `DatePicker`.

I want to set todays date automatically in the spinner. This i do with `setText` now but can't do that with a spinner

I just need help with the Spinner behavior right now, the rest should be quite easy.

Comment: Post what you have so far for your `Spinner`. Typically, you would use an `adapter` with an `Array` or something similar to populate the `Spinner` so I'm not sure what you are going for

Comment: I have casted the spinner so far and got the xml done. In the xml there is an option "android:spinnerMode="dialog"" but i don't know what to do with that.

I am going for the same thing that happens in the android contacts app when you set up a birthday or ther date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Button. With Spinner style.

Just take a look:

```
<Button style="android:Widget.Holo.Spinner"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="whatever you want"/>
```

(this will work only on devices supporting API level >= 4.0 - ice-cream sandwich)

Bind `onClick` and create `AlertDialog` with `DatePicker` view.

If you use ActionBarSherlock then next is more preferred:

```
<Button style="Widget.Sherlock.Spinner.DropDown.ActionBar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="whatever you want"/>
```

(this will work everywhere - tested)

Comment: Thank you so much, this seems to be the solution i was looking for. Awesome.

Answer (score 0):

This is from the documentation:

```
Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
// Create an ArrayAdapter using the string array and a default spinner layout
ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
        R.array.planets_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
// Specify the layout to use when the list of choices appears
adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
// Apply the adapter to the spinner
spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
```

---

```
  for (int i = 0; i < b; i++) {
                View v = spinner.getChildAt(i);
                if (v == null) {
                    System.out.println("View not found");
                } else {


                     v.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View v) {
                                     showDialog(DATE_DIALOG_ID);
                                        }
                       });


----------
// the callback received when the user "sets" the date in the dialog
private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener mDateSetListener =
        new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

            public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year,
                                  int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {

            }
        };

@Override
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {


      switch (id) {
    case DATE_DIALOG_ID:
        return new DatePickerDialog(this, mDateSetListener, mYear, mMonth,
                mDay);
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: i am displaying todays date in the `TextView` wit `setText` but want to convert the `TextView` to a `Spinner`. I don't think Strings are going to be a matter in this situation